# Change row color in javascript

Tags: html

How to change the color of the specific row in a table in javascript

```
foreach($this->paginator as $record)
        {
  echo "<td width='61'> <a href='#' class='test' data-id='" . $record['id']. "'>".     $record['id'] . "</td>";
           echo "<td width='61'>". $record['firstname'] . "</td>";

   }
```

Comment: Not enough information. Which row? And you're outputting columns there, not a row. Post some HTML or set up a JSBin or something.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="background-color: #123"` to the tr-element containing the td elements.

Comment: $('table tr:eq('+index+')').css("background-color", "FF0000");is the solution for this question

Answer (score 0):

You may try this using CSS like;

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Or jQuery like;

```
$("#Your-ID > li:nth-child(odd)").addClass("odd");
```

Comment: @blasteralfred.Many thanks for ur reply..Right now am doing onclick of column dispalying a popup.Onclick of button in the popup,it must change the color of the entire row.I dont know how to do that

Comment: can you post a demo at jsfiddle.net and post here the link?

Comment: yeah am sorry friend.Am able to achieve the code with this statement                                    $('table tr:eq('+index+')').css("background-color", "FF0000");

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to color a specific row

```
$('table tr:eq(3)').addClass('highlight')
```

Replace the number (3) with the index of the row you want to highlight. It's probably a better idea to do this server side though: Render the 'highlight' class on the backend.

Comment: ,Thanks for your valuable reply.How to get the index of the row.Right now am doing onclick of column dispalying  a popup.Onclick of button in the popup,it must change the color of the entire row.I dont know how to do that